# JAXB: Convert Javabean Object to XML all properties as XML attributes rather than XML elements (node)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Currently I'm working on converting object to XML, I notice all object properties are listed as XML elements (node) unless you use  @XmlAttribute on a particular getter or setting

Just wondering is there a way to automatically convert all object properties as XML attributes in JAXB.

Sample Code:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( foo.class );
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
Foo foo = new foo();
foo.setType("type");
foo.setValue("value");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
m.marshal(foo, baos);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

There currently isn't a way to configure that by default simple properties should map to XML attributes.  The following enhancement request has been filed for MOXy to add this behaviour.

- [**Bug 333604**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/333604) - Enhancement: Provide metadata to default simple properties to attributes (instead of elements)

Comment: Thanks! I will probably in the meantime work on other way around the issue. Please keep us updated!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using @XmlRootElement on the class top level?

Comment: `@XmlRootElement` isn't required as you can wrap the root object in an instance of `JAXBElement`:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

Comment: Yeah that was not related to question too, I read it wrong. But there isnt any config to do the one asked in question @Blaise?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JAXB for a complex schemata, it's a good idea to define the structure in a `XSD`:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://myUri"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="parent">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="child" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:long"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="child">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:long"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="code" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

This can be compiled with `jaxb-xjc` to `.java` files and you will have the defined xsd:attributes as attributes in Java.

Comment: Yep, but does this mean every time we introduce a new element, we have to update XSD as well ?

Comment: Well, you only have to update the XSD, compile it and then you have the Java files. At least you have to introduce the element _somewhere_ ;-) IMO the XSD is a lot easier compared to a Java file with JAXB annotations.

Comment: Thanks it helps, sorry I don't have enough reputation to give a vote :S